# Exclude specific OS from Play Store?

Tags: android, google-play

I've got an app published that works well on all Android version from 4.2 up through current *except* for 7.0 (which crashes).  7.0.1 and higher in the 7.x series are fine, it's just the very first 7.0 release that has a problem.  Unfortunately there are *still* people on that release that haven't upgraded to even 7.0.1.  Is there a way to exclude just that one version from our compatible products list?

Comment: I don't think it is possible from Google play console. Why don't you fix the crash and submit the update so that the app will automatically be updated in those devices too?

Comment: you cannot exclude specific os versions

Comment: @NabinBhandari Lack of resources and it's a soon to be deprecated/replaced app...